# PHP function inside of function with changing variable

Tags: php, mysql

Is somehow possible to do something like this?

In result i need one function where I can insert more sql selection with date updating...

```
 function my_try($SQL_SELECTION){
        global $conn, $date1, $date2;
        $now  = gmdate('Y-m-t');
        $loop = 0;
    
        $result = array();
    
        while ($date2 <= $now) {
            // $orders_completed = $conn->query(sql_selection_1($date1, $date2)); // Original.
            $orders_completed = $conn->query($SQL_SELECTION($date1, $date2)); // Here I need to update sql with new date selection.
            $result[] = $orders_completed;
    
            $date2 = gmdate('Y-m-t', strtotime($date2 . '+30 days'));
            $loop++;
        }
    
        return $result;
    }
    
    
    function sql_selection_1($date_from, $date_till) {
        $sql = "SELECT '$date_till'..";
        return $sql;
    }

    function sql_selection_2($date_from, $date_till) {
        $sql = "SELECT '$date_till'...";
        return $sql;
    }
    
    my_try( sql_selection_1() );
    my_try( sql_selection_2() );
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you know all the dates from and all the dates until. Why not working with arrays? Let 's have a look, how we can solve your issue.

```
$data = [
    [
        'date_from' => '2019-10-29',
        'date_till' => '2020-10-28',
    ],
    [
        'date_from' => '2020-10-29',
        'date_till' => '2021-10-28',
    ],
];
```

Just collect all the date intervals in an array and then write a function, that iterates over that array.

```
function intervalIteration(PDO $database, array $data): array
{
    $sql = "SELECT row.id FROM table row WHERE row.date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2";
    $stmt = $database->prepare($sql);

    $rowsets = [];
    foreach ($data as $interval) {
        $result = $stmt->execute([
            'date1' => $interval['date_from'],
            'date2' => $interval['date_until'],
        ]);

        if ($result === false) {
            // some fancy code to deal with execution errors
        }

        $rowset = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($rowset === false) {
            // some fancy code to deal with fetch errors
        }

        // at this point you could update the found rowset with another sql statement

        $rowsets[] = $rowset;
    }
    
    return $rowsets;
}
```

The above function takes the `$data` array we 've defined. This array contains our date intervals. The function takes also a `$database` PDO object, because working with `global` should be avoided. That 's not how to code these days. The function iterates over the `$data` array and fetches a single rowset from the database, where the interval is between the two mentioned dates.

You could do even better by creating a more complex sql query, which matches all rowsets with the given date intervals at once. With this sql query you could use the `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` method and iterate over the results.

Keep in mind, that the above shown code is not a working solution that matches exactly your problem. It shows how you can work with arrays and iteration to solve your issue.